# QHttpServer add route with multiple args

Tags: c++, qt, variadic-templates, qt6, c++-templates

Help to deal with QHttpServer. I know QHttpServer is in preview at the moment.
I have the following code to add routes to the server:

```
template<typename  Args>
bool addHandlerWithParams(const QString &_route, QHttpServerRequest::Method _method, std::function<QHttpServerResponse(const QVariantMap&, Args&)>f)
{
    // example: POST http://127.0.0.1/test/<arg>
    
    return m_restServer->route(_route, _method, [this, f](const Args& args, const QHttpServerRequest &_req){
        QVariantMap value;
        const auto body = byteArrayToJsonObject(_req.body());
        if (body)
            value = (*body).toVariantMap();
        return QtConcurrent::run([value, args, f]()
        {
            Args arg = args;
            return f(value, arg);
        });
    });
}
```

Here, each handler receives 2 arguments: json from the request body (checking for the presence of the body and format is omitted) and a parameter from the request.
This works great. But due to the fact that I am not very well versed in template C ++, the question arose: how to add a handler for multiple parameters (http://127.0.0.1/test//)?

I tried using variadic templates but I'm very bad at it and in the end I just got an error that it's impossible to infer type from std::frunction<Args..., const QVariantMap&>

Answer (score 0):

Just simple example, m_srv is a pointer to QHttpServer instance:

```
m_srv->route("/<arg>/<arg>/", QHttpServerRequest::Method::Get, [this](const QString &firstArg, const QString &secondArg, const QHttpServerRequest &request) {
    qDebug() << firstArg << secondArg;
    return "Ok";
});
```

Comment: The question was how to create your own `addHandlerWithParams` wrapper for a different number of arguments, and not how to pass these arguments to QHttpServer